# Inviting users django-allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

There is a flow that I would like to introduce, we're already using allauth and wanted to try and make it work with allauth (potentially adding another package):

1. New user is invited by specifying his email (only. no password required)
2. The user gets an email, clicks on the invite link and gets to a form where his email is already filled-in, he needs to fill-in more fields such as password, first & last name and some custom fields that I will add to the User model
3. User clicks on confirm and is logged-in, redirected to the root URL

Comment: You can create a custom registration form & view that gets the email address as a GET parameter and prefills the user instance.

Comment: https://github.com/arctelix/django-invitation

Answer (score 5):

[django-invitations](https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations) is a generic invitations solution that was once a plugin to django-allauth but is now stand alone.

- There is an admin interface which allows the creation of invites
- The email sent to the user is based off a template which is easy to override
- Url of `account_signup` is where the user gets directed to which you need to implement

Step 3, you will need to implement yourself

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post but I think it will help others in the future.

I've been working on this and couldn't find any libraries that are stable or actually do what I am looking for. However, I studied the code of RegisterSerializer from `rest_auth` and then created my own to override specific methods in RegisterSerializer.

Here is my final code:

```
class UserInviteSerializer(RegisterSerializer):

    # first_name and last_name were required for my case but they are not necessary.
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    # override password1 and password2 to not be required.
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    # override validate so that you don't get the error that
    # password1 and password2 are required. 
    def validate(self, data):
        return data

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(UserInviteSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()

        return {
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
        }

    # create your own create method.
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = models.User(**validated_data)

        # this is really important because password is required 
        # by the User model. So you need to use the django method
        # `set_unusable_password`
        user.set_unusable_password()

        # username was not being generated by AllAuth so I had to set it.
        user.username = user.email

        user.save()
        return user
```

Now you can create other views to let the user set their password and you can check if they have already a usuable password or not using the django user method `has_usable_password()`